# task triggers in task scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I had a task in my task scheduler which was running every 1 Hour. but it suddenly stopped working and when I run it without trigger it runs correctly, but after setting a trigger it stops working. Anyone knows what is problem? I restarted the server, I set a time for future, but still dosn't work.

Comment: I have found a way to fix it. I just selected "run with the highest privileges" in General window in task scheduler and every thing was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just selected *"run with the highest privileges"* in General window in task scheduler and everything worked fine.